# Visualization of the distribution of times over different trials

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to visualize the distribution of times using their median and IQR for the control (blue) and the intervention (orange) group of different trials like in my example created by powerpoint.

I have only aggregated data in the following format:

```
trial.name (string)
group.A.median (int)
group.A.lower (int)
group.A.upper (int)
group.B.median (int)
group.B.lower (int)
group.B.upper (int)
```

Is it possible to visualize the data as suggested in my example by means of ggfplot2 or another package using R?

If not, any other suggestion besides powerpoint?

I would really appreciate your help!

[image: plot example]

Comment: The bxp function does that plotting part of the base graphics boxplot using the aggregated lresults computed by boxplot.stats. You should be able to either use that code directly or do some hacking. Might need to do it in two stesp, first setup the plot ranges based on the full dataset but plot only group.A and then use a second `bxp` call with add=TRUE for group.B with different box colors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(group = rep(c('A', 'B'), e = 4),
                 med = ifelse(group == 'A', rnorm(8), rnorm(8, 1.5)),
                 lwr = med - 0.2,
                 upr = med + 0.2,
                 trial = rep(1:4, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(trial, med, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, fill = group)) +
  geom_crossbar(width = 0.2) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: why use `tidyverse` here?  `ggplot2` is sufficient

Comment: I also use data_frame.

Comment: @Axeman: Thanks!! That looks great!